# Completing underscored words without making _ a word character

Tags: evil, completion, syntax

I would like to use `evil-complete-previous` (or whatever) to
complete `strings_such_as_this`, which is by default not possible.
It is possible after `(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")`, but this
has the undesired side-effect of rendering it impossible to jump
from the beginning of the string to the third `s` with
`(evil-forward-word-begin)` (`w`).  Can I get the effect without
the side-effect?

Comment: What about M-x dabbrev-expand RET ?

Comment: @AndreasRöhler, it doesn't appear to behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but it works.

```
(defun evil*-complete-previous () (interactive)
     (let ((old (string (char-syntax ?_))))
       (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")
       (evil-complete-previous)
       (modify-syntax-entry ?_ old)))

(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "M-p") 'evil*-complete-previous)
```